# How to change the panel theme in r?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

How can I get a panel with horizontal lines as shown in this plot? I tried all themes but no one provided me with this kind of panel.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean the y axis grid lines? This depends on the plot (base R `plot`, `ggplot`, ...). You don't provide any data or reproducible code example, so providing help is a guessing game. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions, and then edito your question to include a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), including sample data.

Comment: Dear Maurits. Thank you. I only mean the grid itself regardless of the data or the plot. I just want the grid to include horizontal lines as shown in the graph. I used this code but I got different theme:
ggplot() + geom_bar(aes(x=Year, y=Value, fill=Gender), data = graduates1, stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.5) + 
  theme_minimal()

Comment: Please see my answer below. For future posts, *always* include a minimal representative sample dataset, as detailed in the how to make a minimal reprex link. You'll attract a lot more attention here on SO if you make it as easy as possible for people to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `panel.grid.major.x` and `panel.grid.minor.x` to disable the `x` axis grid lines.

Example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Species, y = Sepal.Length)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(
        panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

See [here](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) for a comprehensive list of `theme` parameters.

Comment: @Rami_Kh This is only a minimal example. Obviously you'll need to adjust it to your actual data (**which you don't provide!**). You control the x-axis grid lines with `panel.grid.major.x` and `panel.grid.minor.x`; this won't change any colours of any bars, nor any y-axis scales! Just add the `+ theme(...)` line to your plot and work from there.

Comment: Yes. It worked very well with me right now. Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome @Rami_Kh; please consider closing this question by setting the green check mark next to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to explore existing questions on the same topic. Anyways, it is really simple with ggplot2.

I tried this with mpg data.

library(tidyverse)

```
plt <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x=displ, y=hwy)) + 
        geom_point()
```

It will look like this -
[image]

```
plt + theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
            panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
            panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

Now it will change to -

[image]

Also look at this link - http://r-statistics.co/